# React native <View> doesn't work inside if statment

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
function sumbit_Login(val, val1, nav) {
  const we = val.length
  const we1 = val1.length
  if (we <= 15) {
    alert('Invaild Email')
    return (
      <View style={{ width: 50000, height: 50000, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
      </View>
    )
  }
  if (we1 <= 5) {
    alert('Invaild Password')
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    nav.navigate('Main')
  }
// I use it here out the function (inside another function)

   <View style={{ marginBottom: 10, width: "80%", marginLeft: '10%', marginTop: '-8%' }}>
      <Button
       title="Login"
       onPress={() => sumbit_Login(value, value1, navigation)}
        />
   </View>
```

The view doesn't work in if statement anyone have another way or solve the problem i use the function inside a button but the 'View' inside return doesn't work (I don't get any error.)

Comment: where are you exactly using this function ? update your answer

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"?

Comment: do you get any errors? I miss a semi-colon behind the return statement

Comment: @BrakkeBaviaan it is javascript... there is no need for a semi-colon

Comment: I didn't test the code myself, however inside of the return statement there are JSX expressions, which behave slightly different than regular javascript (and in those cases, adding semi colon still is best practice imo, but maybe I am a fool for this and it is not necesarry at all :'p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the View anywhere in the component tree, try to trace your code, you're calling a function `onPress`, which is a callback and isn't really inside your render hierarchy, if I understand your use case correctly, you're doing this the wrong way..

The way that should be done is to have a state control the visibility of the view when you want to render it and when you don't, here's an example:

```js
function SomeComponent({ navigation }) {
  // Create a state for the visiblity
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
  
  function onSubmit(val, val1) {
    const we = val.length
    const we1 = val1.length
    if (we <= 15) {
      alert('Invaild Email')
      // Set visiblity to true in order to show the View
      setVisible(true)
      return
    }
    if (we1 <= 5) {
      alert('Invaild Password')
      return;
    }
    else {
      navigation.navigate('Main')
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ marginBottom: 10, width: "80%", marginLeft: '10%', marginTop: '-8%' }}>
      <Button
       title="Login"
       onPress={() => sumbit_Login(value, value1, navigation)}
        />
      {
        // Conditionally render the View
        visible && <View style={{ width: 50000, height: 50000, backgroundColor: 'red' }}> 
      }
    </View>
  )
}
```

I suggest you read more docs about react and react native, dos and don'ts, and the best practices for dealing with the lifecycle

Hope you find this helpful